# Python: numpy/pandas change values on condition

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, conditional-statements, transformation

I would like to know if there is a faster and more "pythonic" way of doing the following, e.g. using some built in methods.
Given a pandas DataFrame or numpy array of floats, if the value is equal or smaller than 0.5 I need to calculate the reciprocal value and multiply with -1 and replace the old value with the newly calculated one. 
"Transform" is probably a bad choice of words, please tell me if you have a better/more accurate description.

Thank you for your help and support!!

**Data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dicti = {"A" : np.arange(0.0, 3, 0.1), 
         "B" : np.arange(0, 30, 1),
         "C" : list("ELVISLIVES")*3}
df = pd.DataFrame(dicti)
```

**my function:**

```
def transform_colname(df, colname):
    series = df[colname]    
    newval_list = []
    for val in series:
        if val <= 0.5:
            newval = (1/val)*-1
            newval_list.append(newval)
        else:
            newval_list.append(val)
    df[colname] = newval_list
    return df
```

**function call:**

```
transform_colname(df, colname="A")
```

****--> I'm summing up the results here, since comments wouldn't allow to post code (or I don't know how to do it).****

**Thank you all for your fast and great answers!!**

using ipython "%timeit" with "real" data:

**my function:**
10 loops, best of 3: 24.1 ms per loop

**from jojo:**

```
def transform_colname_v2(df, colname):
    series = df[colname]        
    df[colname] = np.where(series <= 0.5, 1/series*-1, series)
    return df
```

100 loops, best of 3: 2.76 ms per loop

**from FooBar:**

```
def transform_colname_v3(df, colname):
    df.loc[df[colname] <= 0.5, colname]  = - 1 / df[colname][df[colname] <= 0.5]
    return df
```

100 loops, best of 3: 3.32 ms per loop

**from dmvianna:**

```
def transform_colname_v4(df, colname):
    df[colname] = df[colname].where(df[colname] <= 0.5, (1/df[colname])*-1)
    return df
```

100 loops, best of 3: 3.7 ms per loop

Please tell/show me if you would implement your code in a different way!

One final QUESTION: (answered)
How could "FooBar" and "dmvianna" 's versions be made "generic"? I mean, I had to write the name of the column into the function (since using it as a variable didn't work). Please explain this last point! 
--> thanks jojo, ".loc" isn't the right way, but very simple df[colname] is sufficient. changed the functions above to be more "generic". (also changed ">" to be "<=", and updated timing)

Thank you very much!!

Comment: @jojo: Thank you!! Your solution is more pythonic, but slower. My function: 10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop. Your version: 1000 loops, best of 3: 395 µs per loop.

Comment: How does your speed test look like? It's hard to be faster than numpy... at least in python. ;)

Comment: @tryptofame just try to benchmark with a non-trivial sized frame, both solns below will be MUCH faster)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are talking about **arrays**:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], dtype=np.float)
print 1 / a[a <= 0.5] * (-1)
```

This will, however only return the values smaller than `0.5`.

Alternatively use `np.where`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], dtype=np.float)
print np.where(a < 0.5, 1 / a * (-1), a)
```

Talking about `pandas` **DataFrame**:

As in **@dmvianna**'s answer (so give some credit to him ;) ), adapting it to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df.a = df.a.where(df.a > 0.5, (1 / df.a) * (-1))
```

Comment: Hehe, .head() will return only 5 elements or so... I was using it to test with a sample. ;7)

Answer (score 6):

The typical trick is to write a general mathematical operation to apply to the whole column, but then use indicators to select rows for which we actually apply it:

```
df.loc[df.A < 0.5, 'A']  = - 1 / df.A[df.A < 0.5] 

In[13]: df
Out[13]: 
            A   B  C
0        -inf   0  E
1  -10.000000   1  L
2   -5.000000   2  V
3   -3.333333   3  I
4   -2.500000   4  S
5    0.500000   5  L
6    0.600000   6  I
7    0.700000   7  V
8    0.800000   8  E
9    0.900000   9  S
10   1.000000  10  E
11   1.100000  11  L
12   1.200000  12  V
13   1.300000  13  I
14   1.400000  14  S
15   1.500000  15  L
16   1.600000  16  I
17   1.700000  17  V
18   1.800000  18  E
19   1.900000  19  S
20   2.000000  20  E
21   2.100000  21  L
22   2.200000  22  V
23   2.300000  23  I
24   2.400000  24  S
25   2.500000  25  L
26   2.600000  26  I
27   2.700000  27  V
28   2.800000  28  E
29   2.900000  29  S
```

Comment: don't chain index, use ``df.loc[..., ...] = value``!

Comment: True. In my defense, it's the first day after vacations :)

Answer (score 2):

As in **@jojo**'s answer, but using pandas:

```
df.A = df.A.where(df.A > 0.5, (1/df.A)*-1)
```

or

```
df.A.where(df.A > 0.5, (1/df.A)*-1, inplace=True) # this should be faster
```

.where docstring:

> Definition:  df.A.where(self, cond, other=nan, inplace=False,
> axis=None, level=None, try_cast=False, raise_on_error=True)
>
> Docstring:
> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
> are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.

Comment: FYI, Dataframe is not s sub-class of a np.ndarray (nor has ever been), though it does act like a 2-d ndarray.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff, I must have skipped history class. I did assume that due to its behaviour. pandas seems to be very compatible with numpy.