# Apply a conditional function to billions of data points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
idx    a      b      c      d      e      f      g      h      i       j
1      0     17     17     83     17      0     21     16     21       4
2     -9     31     31     74     40      0     39     39     39       9
3    -27      0    -27     92     27    -37      3    -37     40      16
4     -4      0     -4     81      4     -1      5      5      6       9
```

I'd like to apply:

```
where x>0: functionA(x)

where x<0: functionB(x)
```

What I've tried independently:

`df[df>0] = np.log(df)`

and

`df[df<0] = -np.log(-df)`

Which kinda seems to work.. Running these two ops sequentially will not work because the dataframe converts from int to float after the first operation and renders original values un-differentiable from log values, ex. is it a 0 or log(1) = 0 ?

I'm also concerned about these errors:

Divide by zero

````
usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.```
````

Invalid value

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/ds/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
      """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

Which shouldn't occur because there are no `NaN` values and I'm explicitly selecting non zero values.

```
df.isnull().values.any()
False
```

The final issue is how to do this efficiently as I'm working with billions of rows.

Comment: What is the problem with the numbers being converted to float?

Comment: Numbers might be close to zero which messes with floating point math. Its better to compute abs(x-0) < eps, where eps is small: around 10^-5.  Because of this, I think its best to compute the two operations on separate int dataframes and then merge them.

Comment: I don't get the conversion to float part. I understand that log can compute really small values, but since you're complaining about getting `float` then what's the purpose of doing `log`? You could always convert the whole dataframe to `float32` while loading/creating

Comment: There no complaint about going to float. The issue is about applying the two operations on the same dataframe. After one operation the df is mutated into a float32 with log values. Then its no longer possible to differentiate original values vs log values, i.e. is value 0 or log(1) = 0? I've removed that part from the title as its unnecessary and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `numpy.piecewise` function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html

```
import numpy as np
positive = df.values > 0
negative = df.values < 0
df[:] = np.piecewise(df.values, (positive, negative), (np.log, lambda x: -np.log(-x)))
```

Comment: Seems like it should work but I'm getting this error: `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 54572193 to array axis with dimension 10`

Comment: `negative = df.values < 0` (logical_not of > is <= which includes 0. This seems to work, though have to reconvert to df. Thanks!

Here the code I tried:
    
     `positive = df.values > 0
     negative = df.values < 0
     df = np.piecewise(df.values, [positive, negative], [lambda x: np.log(x), lambda x: -np.log(-x)])`

Comment: @encore2097 Sorry about inclusion of 0s into negatives. I fixed this in the latest edit. I also added how to assign values of the new `numpy` array back to your `dataframe`.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way but for now here's what I did:

Broke down my columns into three types:

1. (-inf,0)
2. (0, inf)
3. (-inf, inf)

The first two are straightforward [1]:

```
for i in [a, ...]:
    s = df[i]
    df[i] = np.where(s<0, -np.log(-s), s).astype('float32')
```

Similar code for type 2.

Type 3 was trickier and slower:

```
def apply_log(x):
    if x>0:
        return np.log(x)
    elif x<0:
        return -np.log(-x)
    elif x == 0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        assert False
```

Then vectorize it [2]

`veclog = np.vectorize(apply_log)`

Then run it:
`df['c'] = veclog(s.astype('float32')).astype('float32')`

Runtime on ~50M subset:
`57.7 s ± 142 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

From [3] with `np.where` , the fn is applied before the condition, hence the divide by zero error. Type 1 and 2 throw the divide by zero warnings/errors, no errors on Type 3.

Sources:

[1] [Python: numpy/pandas change values on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326649/python-numpy-pandas-change-values-on-condition)

[2] [Function application over numpy's matrix row/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079061/function-application-over-numpys-matrix-row-column)

[3] [RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610198/runtimewarning-divide-by-zero-encountered-in-log)

Answer (score 0):

Someone added this answer before and then deleted it:

`df = np.log(df.where(df>0)).fillna(-1*np.log(-1*df.where(df<0))).fillna(0)`

Which uses a chunk of memory but appears to work. <s>I have a suspicion it was deleted because it runs the ops in sequence and might clobber some values.</s>

**Update**: This seems to match the answer of other solutions within .0005. Would like if the original poster would re-post their answer!